# How to import and merge PDFs from multiple external folders using a GUI?

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

I've been trying to make a boring job easier with automation.

Combine 2 PDFs from separate windows folders and save into a different output folder.

I choose a single document from a folder that is then merged individually (using a loop) with a number of different front page PDF documents found in a folder that I choose. They are then saved into a separate folder (as PDF). To get these files and folders I'm using tkinter.

I'm learning python and have used a parts from many tutorials to create my frankenstein but it's almost there. I have a feeling that when I choose one folder, it forgets the last folder and when I run the program it can't locate the first folder? Anyway, here's my script... any help would be very much appreciated as the task that was meant to save me time is now taking over my life lol!

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import os
import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
#import PyPDF2
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title('Batch PDF Single to Many Merger')
root.configure(background="light green")
root.minsize(width=500,height=100)
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

def open_coverletter_folder():
    global coverletter_directory
    coverletter_directory=askdirectory()
    f = open(coverletter_directory, 'rb')
    print(coverletter_directory)

def open_cvselect():
    global cv_select
    cv_select=askopenfilename()
    f1 = open(cv_select,'rb')
    print(cv_select)
    #CV = fitz.open(cv_select)

def pdfoutputfolder():
    global output_directory
    output_directory=askdirectory()
    print(output_directory)

def globconvert():
    pdf_file = ['coverletter_directory',"rb",'cv_select',"rb"]
    combine = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in pdf_file:
        combine.append(pdf)
    combine.write('Cover+CV.pdf')
    combine.close()

cover_btn = Button(root,text="Choose Cover Folder",width=25, command=open_coverletter_folder,bg="blue",fg="white")
cover_btn.grid(row=1,column=0,padx = 15,pady =15)

CV_btn = Button(root,text="Choose CV",width=25, command=open_cvselect,bg="blue",fg="white")
CV_btn.grid(row=1,column=1,padx = 15,pady =15)

output_btn = Button(root,text="Choose Output Folder",width=25, command=pdfoutputfolder,bg="brown",fg="white")
output_btn.grid(row=1,column=2)

convert_btn = Button(root,text="Convert PDFs",width=25, command=globconvert,bg="black",fg="white")
convert_btn.grid(row=2,column=0)

exit_btn = Button(root,text="Exit Application",width=25, command=root.destroy,bg="Purple",fg="white")
exit_btn.grid(row=2,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to merge all PDF files inside `coverletter_directory` with PDF file `cv_select` into `Cover+CV.pdf` inside `output_directory` file by file.

Below are the required changes:

```py
# initialize to whatever values you want
coverletter_directory = None
output_directory = None
cv_select = None

def open_coverletter_folder():
    global coverletter_directory
    coverletter_directory = askdirectory()
    #f = open(coverletter_directory, 'rb') ### you cannot open a folder like this
    print(coverletter_directory)

def open_cvselect():
    global cv_select
    cv_select = askopenfilename()
    #f1 = open(cv_select,'rb')  ### you don't need to open it
    print(cv_select)

def pdfoutputfolder():
    global output_directory
    output_directory = askdirectory()
    print(output_directory)

def globconvert():
    # make sure all required parts are ready
    if coverletter_directory and cv_select and output_directory:
        # get all PDF filenames inside coverletter_directory
        pdf_file = [f for f in os.listdir(coverletter_directory) if f.lower().endswith(".pdf")]
        # start merging files
        for pdf in pdf_file:
            srcfile = os.path.join(coverletter_directory, pdf)
            outfile = os.path.join(output_directory, pdf)
            print(f"{srcfile} --> {outfile}")
            combine = PdfFileMerger()
            combine.append(srcfile)
            combine.append(cv_select)
            combine.write(outfile)
            combine.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("PDF Merge", f"Total {len(pdf_file)} PDF files created")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("PDF Merge", "Please select covers folder, CV and output folder")
```

Comment: You're a legend!! Thanks a lot :) Almost there... it isn't looping through the whole selected folder and printing each separately. It's printing all of the PDFs in the folder as a single PDF. For example I'm getting Cover1,2,3 + CV.pdf but need instead Cover1 + CV.pdf then Cover2 + CV.pdf then Cover3+ CV.pdf etc... Any tips?

Comment: Do you actually want to combine each PDF file inside `coverletter_directory` with `cv_select` and save it to `output_directory`? That is `coverletter_directory/file1.pdf + cv_select.pdf -> output_directory/file1.pdf`, `coverletter_directory/file2.pdf + cv_select.pdf -> output_directory/file2.pdf`, etc.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have to send out multiple covers with the same CV. I put all of the covers into a single folder but use the same CV. I am also trying to put them into a separate 'processed' folder I've called 'Output Folder'. To make each unique, I have been trying to add a timestamp so they don't save over themselves... Another possibility would be to use the original cover letter file path name but I think that would be too much effort?